# Can't run Jupiter Notebook on Mac m1

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, apple-m1

Just reinstalled Anaconda on my Mac m1, and now when I try and open Jupyter Notebook using the command line, it gives me this error:

```
jupyter notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/alborzgharabaghi/opt/anaconda3/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 7, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "/Users/alborzgharabaghi/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 49, in <module>
    from zmq.eventloop import ioloop
  File "/Users/alborzgharabaghi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/zmq/__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    _load_libzmq()
  File "/Users/alborzgharabaghi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/zmq/__init__.py", line 32, in _load_libzmq
    from . import libzmq
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/alborzgharabaghi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/zmq/libzmq.cpython-38-darwin.so, 10): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/alborzgharabaghi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/zmq/libzmq.cpython-38-darwin.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /Users/alborzgharabaghi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/zmq/libzmq.cpython-38-darwin.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You said "reinstalled" -- did it used to work? Also, are you in a Rosetta/x86 terminal or a default M1 terminal?

Comment: So it used to work yes, but for some reason downloading tensorflowjs and was just not working no matter what, it kept saying I didn't have the right channels, even downloading python 3.7 wouldn't work so I tried a reinstall and now I can download tensorflow. I'll try switching terminals that seems like a good idea!

Comment: Ok just duplicated my terminal and made it Rosetta and it's still giving me the same error..

Comment: The "wrong architecture" error definitely suggests you have something that's not compatible with your machine...try making sure you have a 32-bit version of python? I haven't used tensor flow so I'm not sure about its M1 compatibility either.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is coming from the [`pyzmq`](https://pypi.org/project/pyzmq/) library!

Its non-M1 compatible version has probably been installed on your Mac.
You will need to reinstall it with a Rosetta Terminal.

**Step 1:** create a new Rosetta terminal, follow [that tuto](https://www.byran.tech/html/how-to-make-a-rosetta-2-emulated-x86-terminal-on-arm-apple-silicon-chips.html) (or any other on the web)

**Step 2:** open your new Rosetta terminal and re-install `pyzmq`:

```
pip uninstall pyzmq
pip install pyzmq
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been experiencing similar issues with this and other CLI commands with the M1. MacOS ships with an old version of Bash, updating Bash to v5 (and making sure I'm running commands in that environment) cleared up this error for me. This article helped: [Upgrading Bash on MacOS](https://itnext.io/upgrading-bash-on-macos-7138bd1066ba)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30308007)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Encountering a similar issue during my attempt to install the notebook on a Python 3.7.13 virtual environment on my MacBook Pro with M2, I identified the root cause as pyzmq. The challenge stemmed from the fact that, as per the [installation wiki](https://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq/wiki/Building-and-Installing-PyZMQ), the wheel for MacOS arm architecture was exclusively built for Python versions greater than or equal to 3.9. The specific error message surfaced during the pyzmq installation process:

```
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyzmq, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects.
```

To address this, I referred to online blogs and initially resolved the problem by installing Python build dependencies using Homebrew:

```bash
brew install openssl readline sqlite3 xz zlib libffi cython zeromq
```

Subsequently, I activated my Python 3.7 virtual environment and installed pyzmq from source:

```bash
pip install --no-binary pyzmq pyzmq
```

With these steps completed successfully, I was then able to seamlessly install the Jupyter notebook package:

```bash
pip install notebook
```